# AWS Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions' config_options not being used

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using .git to deploy eb (PHP), and in the root folder, I've created folder `.ebextensions` and a file `options.config` with content

```
config_options:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    document_root: /laravel/public
```

However, in the `/var/log/eb-activity.log` and I find the `document_root` is never being set

```
 ++ export PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT=
  ++ PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT=
```

In the S3 package I find the `.ebextensions` is bundled, so what can I do to debug this?

Comment: Were you following http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html? If my answer is correct then that page is wrong as I'm not aware of config_options as a valid setting

Answer (score 2):

The docs state using option_settings rather than config_options (node.js, python and ruby examples use it, however the PHP specific example is for config_options)

```
option_settings:
- namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini':
  option_name: document_root
  value: /laravel/public
```

or shorthand YAML as you are using

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    document_root: /laravel/public
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-optionsettings.html

Also a simple thing but is the .ebextensions folder in the source root and the options.config in the .ebextensions folder? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Comment: I've tried your first config and it didn't work. My config run correctly since I've another "container_commands" in the file and it works. Your 2nd config contain error during deploy.

Comment: It is strange since amazon suggest to use config_options, e.g. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html

Comment: Node.js and Python use option_settings: but as you get errors using that for PHP and the PHP page example is config_options: then it must be different. Hopefully someone else with PHP experience will know, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old issue (the link) but as it is said in [this link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1422):

> Having said that, we were concerned when a number of our customers
>   began reporting issues with setting the Document Root environment
>   configuration. Many of these environments were inexplicably "going
>   red" and failing to update correctly under certain conditions. After
>   some digging, we discovered that while the configuration settings were
>   being written correctly during a configuration update, they weren't
>   being written correctly when a new instance was launched (via Auto
>   Scaling, the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse, or otherwise).

I think your problem is not the configuration, but may be the AMI you are using, which AMI is it? The updated AMI version is:

> Amazon Linux 2012.03

Could you please verify your AMI version? Maybe you are using an old custom one?

**EDIT**

Also in [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html), it says there is a document root  configuration in the AWS EB PHP console:

> **To access the configuration options for your PHP environment**
>
> 1) Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
>
> 2) Navigate to the management console for your environment.
>
> 3) Choose **Configuration**.
>
> 4) In the **Software Configuration** section, choose Edit.
>
> **PHP Settings**
>
> - **Document root** – The folder that contains your site's default page. If
>     your welcome page is not at the root of your source bundle, specify
>     the folder that contains it relative to the root path. For example,
>     /public if the welcome page is in a folder named public.

Maybe you can configure it from the dashboard?